# Text placed below bottom margin that is not footnote

Tags: margins, geometry

I'm using package `geometry` to specify global document margins:

`\usepackage[scale=0.82, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}`

But I have a piece of information that I would like to add on first page on the bottom and somehow override margin limitations set by `geometry` package. Easiest way to say thing that I want achieve: I want to place text on bottom margin (below these 2.5cm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest using the package [textpos](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/textpos). With the optional parameter `absolute`, you can positioning the extra text precisely at the place where you want it to be. It is a robust package, with lot of options and posibilities.  I have included a MWE (the `\blindtext`-package produces dummy text):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.82, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Just to have some dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{50}(150,287)
\noindent Text under bottom margin (below 2.5cm)
\end{textblock}

\blinddoc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have did something like that: `\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\paperheight} \begin{textblock}{0.8}[0.5,0.5](0.5,0.96) \begin{center} \noindent\small{\color{color2}\emph{Text-goes-here_Text-goes-here_Text-goes-here.}} \end{center}
\end{textblock}` http://handyfloss.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/latex-the-textpos-package/ This was very helpfull.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package and its `bottom` option; using the `some` option, the material will only be added in those pages in which you invoke `\BgThispage` explicitly; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.82, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,paperheight=8cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[some,bottom]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{Some test text}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{blue}
\SetBgVshift{1cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]\footnote{A test footnote}\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

I changed the value for `paperheight` and used the `showframe` option only for convenience in the example. Here's an image of the first two pages obtained with my example code:

[image]

Another option would be to use the footer to place the text; this can be done using the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or the [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) packages; an example with `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.82, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,paperheight=8cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{specialfooter}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{Some test text}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{specialfooter}
\lipsum[4]\footnote{A test footnote}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that additional information has been provided (the OP is using `moderncv`), here's an example using this document class and the `background` package:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale=0.82, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[some,bottom]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{Some test text added with the \texttt{background} package}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{blue}
\SetBgVshift{0.5cm}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\email{john@doe.org}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\BgThispage
\section{Education-First page}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Education-Second page}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE:

---

To implement the updated format for the `background` package, you can use:

```
\usepackage[pages=some,placement=bottom,%
color=blue,opacity=1,scale=1,vshift=0.5cm]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={Some test text added with the \texttt{background} package}}
```

instead of:

```
\usepackage[some,bottom]{background}

\SetBgContents{Some test text added with the \texttt{background} package}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{blue}
\SetBgVshift{0.5cm}
```